# WYSIWYG Editor paste not working

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg, editor

I am using default magento editor. when i taste with different browsers i found that **Paste** is not working in editor.

Can anyone suggest me why this happen ?

Comment: Copy works? Try instead of CTRL+C with right mouse click 'Copy' and the same 'Paste'. On every Magento page I use, it's working... Any console errors?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i know short key works but need from icon click not from short key line ctrl+c or ctrl+v.

Comment: Can you provide error with screnshot ..it must be from prototype js is not working properly or some extenstion conflicts. Please paste a screenshot of what error you are getting for better enhancement.

Comment: Not any error. i have checked with default magento 1.9.3 but still not working in default magento. copy text and paste using paste icon from editor.